# Django Tinymced

Tags: django, django-templates

Bom Dia galera estou com meu programa quase pronto, neste momento estou tentando integrar o DJANGO-TINYMCE a minha pagina mais os tutoriais que vi só mostra como usar ele no django adim, a minha duvida é existe essa possibilidade de usar o DJANGO-TINYMCE em um template que eu mesmo fiz? preciso que ele fique parecido com isso:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu admin esta assim com poucos recursos: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei esse post https://github.com/divio/django-tinymce/blob/master/docs/usage.rst, que responde a esta pergunta